# Android EditText Content is Empty, Even When Text is Shown

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-edittext

I have an EditText field that represents an ID number.  That field can either be filled programmatically, using IDField.setText(String) based on the results of a card swipe, or it can be filled manually using the keyboard.

Once the text is filled both methods (auto login--based on swipe, or manual--based on button click) both run the same sign in script.  However when I go to grab the contents of the EditText field, if I edited the text manually I get an empty string returned.  If the text was set programmatically then it works perfectly.

This doesn't make any sense to me.  Is there a reason that editText.getText().toString() would not return the content that is visibly shown in the textbox?

XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_swipeCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/signInID"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="SignInStudent"
    android:text="Swipe ID" />
```

Button Initialization:

```
IDField = (EditText) layout.findViewById (R.id.signInID);
LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { SignInStudent(); } } );
```

Card Swipe:

```
// displays data from card swiping
private Runnable doUpdateTVS = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            //Grab ID Number
            String[] splitMSG = strMsrData.split("=");
            //txtIDNumber.setText(splitMSG[2]);
            IDField.setText(splitMSG[2]);
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            hexString.append("<");
            String fix = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < msrData.length; i++) {
                fix = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & msrData[i]);
                if(fix.length()==1)
                    fix = "0"+fix;
                hexString.append(fix);
                if((i+1)%4==0&&i!=(msrData.length-1))
                    hexString.append(' ');
            }
            hexString.append(">");
            myUniMagReader.WriteLogIntoFile(hexString.toString());

            SignInStudent();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Sign In Logic:

```
public void SignInStudent()
{
    String temp = "http://wwww.tempUrl.com/signIn?ID="+ IDField.getText().toString() + "&DeviceId="+KEY;
    webView.loadUrl(temp);
}
```

Comment: Please edit this with your code? definitely you have some thing wrong in code..

Comment: post your layout xml as well..

Comment: it is probably because your text have not been validated yet. Is it still underlined when you click the button ?

Comment: Please Post your code.

Comment: I've posted the code.

Comment: can you please describe your problem with a little bit more information about when this piece of code is working...while the login is triggered by button click and what do you mean by `auto-login based on swipe` ?

Comment: When you login via cardswipe, SignInStudent(); is called from doUpdateTVS where the IDField text is set programatically.  That section works perfectly.  When you login manually, you type the text in EditText then click a button that triggers SignInStudent();.  when you type the ID in, the edit text field returns an empty string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The layout is only updated during the onCreate phase of the loop.  This is fired when an onResume event is called as well which explains why the fields update after you lock and unlock the device.  There are a few workarounds for this such as doing more background processing and then creating a new view with correct values, or using a surfaceView that allows drawing to occur while the program is in its normal execute cycle.

For my application I either do background processing and then move to a new view, or have a view that just keeps calling itself to get the onCreate events to fire again.  The solution depends on the application, but that's why the problem occurs.